# Responsive css not working in content section

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, firebug

Had spent many hours try to figuring out what makes content wrapper not working.
The site is here:
http://bit.ly/19dWUf

html structure contains header, content and footer.

Its looks good when accessing using firefox, google chrome in dekstop by resizing the window to emulate mobile view.

## The problem

When accessing using mobile devices the content section is right aligned, header n footer looks fine.

[image: the content miss aligned just in MOBILE devices]

since it looks good on firefox and usually use firebug to debug, 
it's hard to find what makes problem in real mobile device. 
i m using Opera Mobile emulator to check the display..

[image: Looks good in Dekstop]

any opinion appreciated. or is there any firebug/similar tools for testing mobile?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your section#content-wrapper gets margin-left and margin-right of 30px upon page load.
Either remove

```
jQuery('#content-wrapper').css({
    'margin-left':'30px',
    'margin-right':'30px'
});
```

from jquery.custom.js (line 332), or change it to

```
'margin': '0 auto'
```

Comment: Thank you brother!... i m not aware about custom js. thank you again